# how to set checked the checkbox when click on the list item?

Tags: listview, checkbox

I'm working on an app that display a list of installed apps.
I added checkbox to each item of this list for select apps
the problem is when i set one of the checkbox state to checked and scroll down, i see some other the checkboxes state has been changed to check
how can i solve this problem??
this is my codes

the AllAppsActivity.java codes:

```
public class AllAppsActivity extends ListActivity {

private PackageManager packageManager = null;
private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new LoadApplications().execute();
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (v != null) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
    }



}

private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
        try {
            if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                applist.add(info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return applist;
}

private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(AllAppsActivity.this,
                R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setListAdapter(listadaptor);
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(AllAppsActivity.this, null,
                "Loading application info...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
}
```

the ApplicationAdapter.java codes:

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
private Context context;
private PackageManager packageManager;

public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
    this.context = context;
    this.appsList = appsList;
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
}

@Override
public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
    return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (null == view) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null);
    }

    ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
    if (null != data) {
        TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        TextView packageName = (TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
        ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

        appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
        packageName.setText(data.packageName);
        iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
    }
    return view;
    }
    };
```

activity_main.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and snippet_list_row.xml codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_paackage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:focusable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of checked contacts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179789/how-to-get-list-of-checked-contacts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep track of which boxes are checked and use this to set checked in `ApplicationAdapter.getView`. This would be in this segment

```
if (null != data) {
        TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        TextView packageName = (TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
        ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

        appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
        packageName.setText(data.packageName);
        iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
    }
```

An implementation could be:
First adapt the Adapter class (pun not intended) to be able to retain if an item is checked

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
    ...
+   private SparseArray<Boolean> checkedList = new SparseArray(); 
    ...

+   public void toggleChecked(int position){
+       checkedList.put(position,!checkedList.get(position,false));
+   }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...

        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != data) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            TextView packageName = (TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
+           CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(data.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
+           checkBox.setChecked(checkedList.get(position,false);
        }
        return view;
        }
    };
```

then one needs to tell the item is clicked in the onListItemClicked of AllApsActivity, this could look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (v != null) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
+       listadaptor.toggleChecked(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Further it looks like you didn't copy the whole xml files and I suggest you to use holders for you adapter views instead of using findViewById each time.

Comment: thanks for answer. so i should keep value of checkboxes right?? but i have one problem, when i added this code `checkBox.setChecked(data.isChecked);` i got error cannot resolve symbol actually **isChecked** have error. i'm not a professional programer can you explain more?

Comment: Where you define applicationInfo add a boolean isChecked, maybe show the ApplicationInfo class and I can tell you more. And don't forget to adapt onListItemClick to

Comment: I do'nt have applicationInfo class all my codes is up here. can you tell me exactly where i define the isChecked? sorry i ask a lot :-(( please explain to me with code for better understanding

Comment: I put the + to show where I added something to your code and ... is where I didn't change anything and I didn't want to rewrite everything.

Comment: thank you very much. :-) you have no idea how much you help me. now if i want save checkboxes state to when colse and open again app i still have checkboxes state ,can i use sharedpreferences?? is there a better way?

Comment: I don't know if you can store a sparsearray in shared preferences but if you can its fine. Otherwise it depends on how long you want to store this data. Either you would use the saved instance bundle or an sql db.

Comment: ok.I think i can store the array in shared preferences. thank you agan;-))